# AlertDialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How can I show in `AlertDialog` two `EditText` and 2 `TextView`?

custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:id="@id/layout_root" android:padding="10.0dip"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Libellé"
 android:id="@+id/Text_Libelle"
/>
 <EditText android:id="@+id/Edit_Libelle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        />
  <EditText android:id="@+id/Edit_Url"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        />
```

On click on button I want to show this interface in alert dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have the layout created so all you have to do is assign it to your custom dialog like so..

Set the custom layout to the dialog after initializing..

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(someContext);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialoglayout); //Set dialog view to custom layout
```

To wire up your handlers you will have to do something to the effect of..

```
EditText myText = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.Edit_Libelle);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: It's not the "StackOverflow way" to spoon feed the code.  I provided the same link that I used when I had that question early on, and there's more than enough right there to get going.  When he comes back and asks "how do I return my dialog's data back to the calling activity", then he's done his work and can get a specific answer to a specific question.  lol

Comment: I didn't want you to provide code. Thats not the way it should be, you're right. Anyway a bit more information like "you have to do that, I recommend you to do that... additional infos can be found here: link" that's the way it should be.